# Users and admin with Doorkeeper and Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

I have a main app, this app has Users and Admins (different model and table)using devise.

The main app use doorkeeper to allow users to authenticate on another service. The client app use Omniauth to consume OAuth2.

I am now reaching a point where the client app need a backend and using the admin users from the main app make sense.

Here is my current strategy :

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class ResaNetwork < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      option :name, :resa_network

      option :client_options, {
        #site: "http://dylog.ubuntu-sylario.net:3000",
        site: ENV["CLIENT_OPTION_SITE"],
        authorize_path: "/oauth/authorize"
      }

      uid do
        raw_info["resource_owner_id"]
      end

      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/api/me').parsed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For doorkeeper I will will use warden scope (I know it has nothing to do with oauth scope) user or admin depending on the oauth2 Scope in resource_owner_authenticator.

- Is it possible to have a specific scope entered has a param with the signin path of omniauth? How?
- Is my use of scope correct or is it a really ugly hack? For info, admin will access users data while users will only see their data in the API.